# How to prove this operator is closed?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $H=L^2[0,1]$, set $T=i\frac{d}{dt}$, and its domain is
$$D(T)=\{u\in H: u \text{ is absolutely continuous, and $u'\in H$ } \}$$
I need to prove $T$ is a closed operator, but I am stuck. Here is what I have tried.

Define the graph norm: for any $u\in H$, let $$||u||_g:=||u||_{L^2}+|| i \frac{du}{dt}||_{L^2}=||u||_{L^2}+||u'||_{L^2}$$
It suffices to prove $D(T)$ is complete under this norm. Suppose there is a Cauchy sequence $\{f_n\}_n\subset D(T)$ with respect to this norm, then we know that $\{f_n\}_n$ and $\{f'_n\}_n$ are Cauchy sequences with respect to the $L^2$ norm, hence have a limit. Let's denote the limit of $\{f_n\}_n$ and $\{f'_n\}_n$ by $u$ and $v$ respectively. Now we need to prove $u(t)=\int_0^t vdt+u(0)$. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea.

We have that a similar identity to the one you wish to obtain holds for $f_n$ and $f_n'$:
\begin{align*}
\int_{[0,t]} f_n'(x) dx = f_n(t)-f_n(0)
\end{align*}
so it would be nice if we could use a theorem to calculate what happens when we try to compute its limits.

For that, you can choose an adequate subsequence for which the convergence can be chosen to also be pointwise almost-everywhere for $f_n$'s subsequence (because $L^2$ convergence implies convergence in measure which tells us there is a subsequence which converges in the desired manner).

Then without loss of generality suppose that $f_n$ converges to $u$ pointwise almost-everywhere (just not to use cumbersome notation for the subsequence). Choose $t_0$ such that $f_n(t_0)\to u(t_0)$, and let $t\in [0,1]$ be another real for which that happens. Suppose that $t>t_0$, and the case $t_0>t$ can be proved similarly. We can see that then:
\begin{align*}
u(t)-u(t_0) = \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(t)-f_n(t_0) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{[t_0,t]} f_n'(x) dx = \int_{[t_0,t]} v(x) dx
\end{align*}
where we use the fact that $L^2$ convergence in $[0,1]$ implies $L^1$ convergence to show the convergence of the integrals and standard (pointwise) convergence to show the convergence of our functions $f_n$ to $u$ in the appropriate values. This tells us that
\begin{align*}
\int_{[t_0,t]} v(x) dx = u(t)-u(t_0)
\end{align*}
almost-everywhere in $[t_0,1]$, and analogously one can verify that:
\begin{align*}
\int_{[t,t_0]} v(x) dx = u(t_0)-u(t)
\end{align*}
almost everywhere in $[0,t_0]$. This implies that $u$ is absolutely continuous in $[0,1]$ with derivative $v$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I wonder why $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{[t_0,t]} f_n'(x)dx=\int_{[t_0,t]} v(x)dx$? Can we find an integrable function to control all $f_n'$?

Comment: I do not know, but I suggest using the fact that $f_n'$ converging in $L^2$ to $v$ implies convergence in $L^1$ for $f_n'$ to $v$ because this is true for measure spaces of finite measure. This can be proved (in many ways, but) for example in this case with Jensen's inequality: $\left(\int_{[t_0,t]} |f_n'(x) - f(x)| dx\right)^2 \leq \int_{[t_0,t]} |f_n'(x) - f(x)|^2 dx \to 0$. Then one can use the fact that convergence in $L^1$ implies convergence of the integrals to conclude the result.